# Domain-registration based blocking

Tags: dns, domain, blocking

What strategy should be utilised to block traffic from domains registered with a specific domain registrar?  (Mac & PC, and phones with both wifi & data connections)

(Yes, it's a blunt defence mechanism, but so many phishing sites in the UK are registered through the same domain registrar and it's got to the point where the best way to protect my family is to block traffic from any site registered through them irrespective of the legitimate sites we'd miss out on).

Edit: to be clear, it's not just a domain or two I'm looking to block after finding out that they are fraudulent, but rather I'm looking to block traffic from *any* domain registered with a particular domain registrar as a pre-emptive step since this registrar has is happy to register domains from criminals time and time again and put very little effort into defending end users.

Comment: Difficult. What traffic *from* specific domains are you referring to? (Please [edit] your question to answer.) When you get incoming traffic, all you see is the IP address. You would have to translate the IP address to a domain name, then do a `whois` lookup of the domain name to find the registrar. The relation from an IP address to a domain name may be ambiguous, and the setup of a reverse lookup is optional. So the first step to get the/a domain name may be difficult. Every lookup needs time. It would be easier to block traffic *to* specific domains using your own DNS server or proxy.

Comment: you have some options. if you run a DNS server, you can add a blackhole zone for that domain. if you don't you can put up a PiHole server, and configure those domains if they are not already present on the blocklist. if you don't want either of these I believe you can subscribe to OpenDNS, and establish your own personal settings for resolution for those domains. of course all of these require the ability to ensure that the device DNS server addresses are using the config you specify, but that will be true with all dns level solutions.